# Erro ao instalar o react native no linux mint

Tags: node.js, linux, react-native

Tento instalar o react native pelo terminal mas só aparece erro:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
npm ERR! Linux 5.0.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 5.0.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/douglas/npm-debug.log
```

Já pesquisei vários tutoriais e até agora nada de solucionar o erro... Eu executo o npm até pelo administrador e mesmo assim tem erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este erro pode ser causado por causa da versao do `npm` que voce esta usando(`v3.5.2`). Tente atualizar o seu npm com o comando `npm install -g npm@latest` e tente executar o comando novamente.
Caso seu erro nao seja resolvido tente atulizar a versao do node para uma versao `v10` para que assim possa ser atualizado seu `npm`. O npm nao ira atualizar se seu node nao estiver em uma versao mais recente, como foi discutido nessa [issue no github](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/681) onde o erro `npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG` semelhante ao seu foi reportado. Tente atulizar seu node para uma versao mais recente e tente novamente.

Comment: Esta é a ultima versão pois já atualizei com este comando e continua o erro

Comment: @DouglasFelipe fiz uma editada na minha resposta. Tente ver se resolve seu problema. Agora que eu vi que seu node esta na versao 8.

Comment: Vlw... Consegui resolver o problema